# Unexpected end of file .bashrc Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: bash, bashrc

This  is my .bashrc file. i tried several time to set android sdk path then my terminal show  this  error   `bash: /home/thiyo/.bashrc: line 121: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

This is  my `.bashrc` file:

```
 # ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
 # see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
 # for examples

 # If not running interactively, don't do anything
 case $- in
 *i*) ;;
  *) return;;
  esac

  # don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
  # See bash(1) for more options
  HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

  # append to the history file, don't overwrite it
  shopt -s histappend

 # for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
 HISTSIZE=1000
 HISTFILESIZE=2000

 # check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
 # update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
 shopt -s checkwinsize

 # If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
 # match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
 #shopt -s globstar

 # make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
 [ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

 # set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
 if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
 debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
 fi

 # set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
 case "$TERM" in
 xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
 esac

 # uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
 # off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
 # should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
 #force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
 if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
# We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
# (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
# a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
color_prompt=yes
else
color_prompt=
fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w                   \[\033[00m\]\$ 'else
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

 # If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
 case "$TERM" in
 xterm*|rxvt*)
 PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
 ;;
 *)
 ;;
 esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
#alias dir='dir --color=auto'
#alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)"          "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like 
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly. 
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
. ~/.bash_aliases
fi
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).

if ! shopt -oq posix; then
if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
. /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
. /etc/bash_completion export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/lib/android-sdk/"
export PATH="${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}tools/:${ANDROID_HOME}platform-tools/"
fi
fiexport ANDROID_HOME="/home/thiyo/Android/Sdk/"

# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
if [ -f '/home/thiyo/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc' ]; then .  '/home/thiyo/google-cloud-       sdk/path.bash.inc'; fi
```

Comment: Did you look at line 121?  See anything ...unususal... there?

Comment: still checking file. but i cant find it

Comment: Status please...

Comment: thank  @heynnema  you correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've heavily modified your ~/.bashrc file. Here's a **closer** attempt at what the ending should look like.

Note: There may be other errors in the ~/.bashrc file. There may be new errors introduced.

**Change:**

```
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).

if ! shopt -oq posix; then
if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
. /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
. /etc/bash_completion export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/lib/android-sdk/"
export PATH="${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}tools/:${ANDROID_HOME}platform-tools/"
fi
fiexport ANDROID_HOME="/home/thiyo/Android/Sdk/"

# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
if [ -f '/home/thiyo/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc' ]; then .  '/home/thiyo/google-cloud-       sdk/path.bash.inc'; fi
```

**To this:**

```
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).

if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

# Android SDK
# Only use ONE of the next two "export ANDROID_HOME" lines...
# export ANDROID_HOME="/home/thiyo/Android/Sdk/"
export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/lib/android-sdk/"
export PATH="${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}tools/:${ANDROID_HOME}platform-tools/"

# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
if [ -f '/home/thiyo/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc' ]; then 
  . /home/thiyo/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc
fi
```

Comment: thank you this is correct

Answer (score 4):

That line:

```
fiexport ANDROID_HOME="/home/thiyo/Android/Sdk/"
```

put a newline between `fi` and `export`

Comment: There's a lot more wrong with their ~/.bashrc file.

Comment: no i change   those all and now ok  

if ! shopt -oq posix; then
if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
. /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
. /etc/bash_completion export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/lib/android-sdk/"
export PATH="${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}tools/:${ANDROID_HOME}platform-tools/"
fi
fiexport ANDROID_HOME="/home/thiyo/Android/Sdk/"